# Passing multiple params to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I trigger stored procedure and pass parameters from Visual Studio to SQL Server stored procedure.

Here is code:

```
var cId = new SqlParameter("@clientId", clientId);

var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DamageEventsDTL>("SPDamageEventsDTL @clientId", cId );
```

But I need to pass multiple parameters (`int`, `DateTime` and list of integers).

Here how I do it:

```
 int clientId = 5;
 DateTime date = new DateTime("2016-07-01");
 List<int> list= new List<int>(new int[] { 2, 3, 5 });

 var cId = new SqlParameter("@clientId", clientId);
 var dateEvents = new SqlParameter("@date", date);
 var freqEvents = new SqlParameter("@list ", list );

 var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DamageEventsDTL>("SPDamageEventsDTL @cId, @date, @list ", cId, dateEvents, list);
```

But it seems to be wrong way.

Any idea what I do wrong here?

Comment: Google `Table Type Parameters for SQL Server Stored Procedures` you can pass your list of numbers to that table type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use an XML to send parameters to SQL, like this:

```
USE tempdb
GO
 DECLARE @Element XML;
          SET @Element='
<SavedOrderElement>
  <Data>
    <Age>5</Age>   
    <Nit>46546546546</Nit>
    <Name>Jeff</Name>   
    <LastName>Thalliens</LastName>
    <Email>VerizonBoughtYahoo@yahoo.com</Email> 
    <PokemonGo>Nothing</PokemonGo>
  </Data>  
</SavedOrderElement>' ;


;WITH ElementSavedOrders
AS
(       
    SELECT 
    CAST(c.query('data(Age)') AS VARCHAR(50)) as Age
    ,CAST(c.query('data(Nit)') AS VARCHAR(50)) as Nit
    ,CAST(c.query('data(Name)') AS VARCHAR(50)) as Name
    ,CAST(c.query('data(LastName)') AS VARCHAR(50)) as LastName
    ,CAST(c.query('data(Email)') AS VARCHAR(100)) as Email  
    ,CAST(c.query('data(PokemonGo)') AS VARCHAR(100)) as PokemonGo  
    FROM @Element.nodes('SavedOrderElement/*') as T(c)                  
)

SELECT * FROM ElementSavedOrders
```